# How can i use http_basic_authenticate_with only on certain subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain, basic-authentication

I wan't my http_basic_authenticate_with to work on the admin subdomain. 
I tried declaring it like this

```
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => ENV["WEBSITE_USERNAME"],
                               :password => ENV["WEBSITE_PASSWORD"],
                               :subdomain => 'admin',
                               :only => ['edit', 'destroy', 'new', 'index']
```

even tried

```
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => ENV["WEBSITE_USERNAME"],
                               :password => ENV["WEBSITE_PASSWORD"],
                               :only => ['edit', 'destroy', 'new', 'index'] if request.subdomain == "admin"
```

but the request variable doesn't exist at that point.

Does anyone know how I can get authentication when admin subdomain is first visited?

Comment: Presuming your admin functions are in their own controller, couldn't you just add the basic authentication to the admin controller? That way you wouldn't have to worry about name changes in the subdomain, etc.

Comment: There actually not, they are in the same controller and my views add functions if admin subdomain is present, example in my index view of my projects if you are on the admin subdomain you see the index page with remove buttons on the sides of each project and an add box up at the top

Answer (score 1):

information about authentication like this in rails is hard to find. I ended up finding a method called

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic
```

More info [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods/authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic)

my end code is

```
before_action :index, :authenticate #this can be a filter as well should you need multiple actions

def authenticate
if request.subdomain == 'admin'
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic("Administration") do |user,pass| user == ENV["WEBSITE_USERNAME"] && pass = ENV["WEBSITE_PASSWORD"] end 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of ruby & rails you can do so with lambdas

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: ENV["HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_USER"], password: ENV["HTTP_BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD"], if: -> { request.subdomain == "admin" }
```